# Problem with static Qt linking (MSVC2017)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, clion

First of all I would say that everything compiles, links and works perfect with standard Qt libs from online installer

Let's begin
I want my app to run standalone (only exe file). I already have downloaded and setup tesseract, leptonica and dependent libs. Only Qt left dynamic. Then I read a lot of instructions how to make it static. I downloaded qt everywhere from this [page](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers). Compiled it with these commands:
`configure -static -release -platform win32-msvc
nmake
nmake install`

Then I replaced Qt/5.13/msvc path with new Qt/5.13 path with compiled static libs

Here is my cmake file (I'm coding in Clion cuz i hate Visual Studio IntelliSens with their tab autocompletion instead of enter)

```
#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(OWStreamRecordEx)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${VCPKG}/installed/x64-windows-static;${QT}/lib/cmake)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Tesseract REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

include_directories(${VCPKG}/installed/x64-windows-static/include)
include_directories(${QT}/include)

set(CompilerFlags
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
        )
foreach(CompilerFlag ${CompilerFlags})
    string(REPLACE "/MDd" "/MTd" ${CompilerFlag} "${${CompilerFlag}}")
endforeach()
add_executable(OWStreamRecordEx src/main.cpp src/mainwindow.cpp src/mainwindow.h src/mainwindow.ui src/ScreenShooter.cpp src/ScreenShooter.h src/SHMEMReader.cpp src/SHMEMReader.h src/VisionThread.cpp src/VisionThread.h)

target_link_libraries(OWStreamRecordEx Qt5::Core)
target_link_libraries(OWStreamRecordEx Qt5::Gui)
target_link_libraries(OWStreamRecordEx Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(OWStreamRecordEx libtesseract)
```

QT and VCPKG is defined by cmake arguments -DVCPKG=...

And finally my problem is it does not link:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'
```

And, I have to clarify that everything works with regular qt

**UPD1:** Link log

```
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\OWStreamRecordEx.dir\objects1.rsp /out:OWStreamRecordEx.exe /implib:OWStreamRecordEx.lib /pdb:D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\ProjectsQt\OWStreamRecordEx\cmake-build-debug\OWStreamRecordEx.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\mpr.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\netapi32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\userenv.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\version.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\ws2_32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\kernel32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\user32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\shell32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\uuid.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\ole32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\advapi32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\winmm.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\mpr.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\netapi32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\userenv.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\version.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\ws2_32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\kernel32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\user32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\shell32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\uuid.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\ole32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\advapi32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\winmm.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\mpr.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\netapi32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\userenv.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\version.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\ws2_32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\kernel32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\user32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\shell32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\uuid.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\ole32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\advapi32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\winmm.lib gdi32.lib comdlg32.lib oleaut32.lib imm32.lib winmm.lib ws2_32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib gdi32.lib comdlg32.lib oleaut32.lib imm32.lib winmm.lib ws2_32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\mpr.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\netapi32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\userenv.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\version.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\ws2_32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\kernel32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\user32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\shell32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\uuid.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\ole32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\advapi32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\winmm.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\shell32.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\uxtheme.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\dwmapi.lib gdi32.lib comdlg32.lib oleaut32.lib imm32.lib winmm.lib ws2_32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib D:\Qts\Qt-5.13.0\lib\Qt5Core.lib D:\Qts\Qt-5.13.0\lib\Qt5Gui.lib D:\Qts\Qt-5.13.0\lib\Qt5Widgets.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\tesseract41d.lib D:\Qts\Qt-5.13.0\lib\Qt5Gui.lib D:\Qts\Qt-5.13.0\lib\Qt5Core.lib D:\Qts\Qt-5.13.0\lib\Qt5Gui.lib D:\Qts\Qt-5.13.0\lib\qtlibpng.lib D:\Qts\Qt-5.13.0\lib\Qt5Core.lib D:\Qts\Qt-5.13.0\lib\qtpcre2.lib D:\Qts\Qt-5.13.0\lib\qtharfbuzz.lib Ws2_32.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\leptonica-1.76.0d.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\gif.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\jpegd.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\libpng16d.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\tiffd.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\lzmad.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\jpegd.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\libpng16d.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\tiffd.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\lzmad.lib D:\Evgeny\Documents\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\zlibd.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\OWStreamRecordEx.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\OWStreamRecordEx.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
```

**UPD2:**

I manually replaced all Program Files with "" and this error has gone, but new one appears, when linking Qt5Core it says

```
Qt5Core.lib(qarraydata.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

How is that possible if I compiled Qt on x64 machine with x64 msvc?

**UPD3:**

Okay, I will try to rebuild qt again with x64 arguments. It will take long (like 8 hours). Hope it will help

Comment: My psychic powers suggest that something of the form `C:\Program Files\Library\Foo.lib` is getting passed to the linker, but it's missing the quotes `""` So the linker sees `c:\Program` and tries to link to that directly.

Comment: @selbie yep, like all guides said. But my Qt and VCPKG on D: drive, so there is no qt or tesseract libs with c:program

Comment: @selbie should I reinstall Visual Studio files into directory with no whitespaces in the name? Or how i can fix that

Comment: How does CMake infer the Visual Studio install directories and that bucket of standard win32 .lib files to link with ?  Once you know that, this should be a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try, instead of

`set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${QT}/lib/cmake)`

write

`list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${QT}/lib/cmake")`

, or maybe even

`list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${QT}\\lib\\cmake")`